# Exception caught by gesture: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'Double' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on add to cart, I get an error after debugging and running the code.
price is defined in the file named product.dart like final double price and in products.dart for 4 products I have separate pricing 49.99, 59.99, ....

[image]

here are my codes:

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/cart.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';

import 'package:my_shop/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: GridTile(
    footer: GridTileBar(
        title: Text(
          product.title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(2 / 3),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(product.isFavorite
                      ? Icons.favorite
                      : Icons.favorite_border),
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  onPressed: () {
                    product.toggleFavoritestatus();
                  },
                )),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          onPressed: () {
            cart.addItem(
                product.id, product.price as Double, product.title);
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('The item added to your cart!'),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
              action: SnackBarAction(label: 'UNDO', onPressed: () {}),
            ));
          },
        )),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
          arguments: product.id,
        );
      },
      child: Image.network(
        product.imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Please help me out and let me know how to fix it.
thanks in advance

Comment: Change `as Double` to `as double`. Capitalization matters; `double` and `Double` are different types.

Comment: does not work even with lowercase as double.

Comment: The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Double'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Unnecessary cast.
Try removing the cast.dartunnecessary_cast
double price
Type: double

package:my_shop/providers/product.dart

Comment: now it's working, I had a mistake capital in my method void addItem with Double instead of double. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have mistakenly written `Double` instead of `double` change this line of code

```dart
cart.addItem(product.id, product.price as Double, product.title);
```

to this

```dart
cart.addItem(product.id, product.price as double, product.title);
```

Comment: I just did it, but another error appeared: The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Double'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Unnecessary cast.
Try removing the cast.dartunnecessary_cast
abstract final class double extends num
dart

Comment: and also when I remove as double, this error exists: The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Double'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Product product
Type: Product

Comment: can you share the code of addItem function

Comment: now it's working, I had a mistake capital in my method void addItem with Double instead of double. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening as you are using your own custom `Double` class for casting the value of `product.price` over here:

`cart.addItem(product.id, product.price as Double, product.title);`

Dart has floating point values as `double`, **NOT** `Double`. The data coming from the db is also coming as a `double` and therefore is throwing an exception when you are already trying to cast an already pre-define data type as something else.

Comment: now it's working, I had a mistake capital in my method void addItem with Double instead of double. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try with that changed

```
cart.addItem(product.id, product.price as Double, product.title);
```

to

```
cart.addItem(product.id, double.parse(product.price.toString), 
product.title);
```